# Select class jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class called formStyle which occurs several times in my webpage. Is it possible to select let's say first and third (with jquery)  if they are five

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yep, like this

```
$('.formStyle:eq(0), .formStyle:eq(2)')
```

Comment: Right, apart from eq being 0 based, so he wants 0 and 2 for the 1st and 3rd item.

Answer (score 6):

You can use jQuery's [`:eq()`-selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/), but it is easier (and probably faster, due to native selectors) to select all of them and pick the ones you need afterwards:

```
var elements = $('.formStyle');
elements.eq(0) // first
elements.eq(2) // third
```

Comment: This is probably the best way of doing it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the eq selector to get a specific index

```
$('.formStyle:eq(0), .formStyle:eq(2)') // Will return the first and 3rd elements with the class formStyle
```

Comment: This is correct. +1! The only problem is that this can be very verbose (depending on the number of elements), since you need to type `.formStyle` over and over again.

Comment: I agree, your way is definitely better :D

Answer (score 2):

You would be much better off giving those elements unique IDs and referencing them by the ID directly. They can still share the same class.